# What is the btree structure of non clustered index with multiple key columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Is SQL Server going to create two or one btree(s) in case of two key columns in index?

E.g.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SAMPLE
ON dbo.SAMPLE(NAME, DEPTNAME)
```

What if we include columns in index? Is it same structure?

Comment: **One** btree, containing elements with **two columns** each. Also: `INCLUDE` only adds those column(s) mentioned at the **leaf level** of the index - those columns are **NOT** part of the index' navigational structures.